# Does ingress TLS secret need a SSL private key for __INGRESS_SECRET__?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm trying to

`kubectl create secret tls foo-secret --key /tls.key --cert /tls.crt`

From keys and certs I've used made from LetsEncrypt. This processes makes sense with self-signed certificates, but the files made by LetsEncrypt look like this:

```
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

I can convert those pem files, I don't know if `--key` want's a public key or a private key, and the only option here is `privkey.pem`. I assume cert is cert.

I can convert `private.pem` with:

`openssl rsa -outform der -in privkey.pem -out private.key`

And `cert.pem` with:

`openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.pem -out cert.crt`

Is this the right process? Since I'll be using this secret for [ingress oauth](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/ingress/blob/master/docs/examples/external-auth/dashboard-ingress.yaml) in place of `__INGRESS_SECRET__`, is this ingress suppose to have a private key? This ingress is acting as a TLS terminator for other things.

Comment: `key` always refers to the private key in an x509 cert. As for the cert itself, you should merge `cert.pem` and `fullchain.pem` into one `tls.crt` file and use that as your public key. You can either use openssl or just merge the files manually, making sure contents of `cert.pem` appear before `fullchain.pem`

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you will need to provide your private key for the `tls.key` portion. However it's a good practice to automate the letsencrypt certificate generate process, using [cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager). Check out this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/automated-tls-with-cert-manager-and-letsencrypt-for-kubernetes-7daaa5e0cae4). Dong so will automatically create the tls secret resource for you on the cluster.

Your **`tls.key`** file is the private key and begins and ends like the following:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

    ... [your private key]

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And your **`tls.crt`** is going to be the concatenation of `cert.pem` and `fullchain.pem`, and it will look like the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

    ...
    [your cert content]

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

    ...
    [your fullchain cert content]

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```